# How to implement map using reduce in Clojure

Tags: clojure, map-function

In the book [Clojure for the Brave and True](http://www.braveclojure.com/clojure-for-the-brave-and-true/) at the end of the section covering [reduce](http://www.braveclojure.com/core-functions-in-depth/#reduce) there's a challenge:

> If you want an exercise that will really blow your hair back, try implementing `map` using `reduce`

It turns out that this was a lot harder (at least for me, a Clojure beginner) than I thought it would be. After quite a few hours I came up with this:

```
(defn map-as-reduce
  [f coll]
  (reduce #(cons (f %2) %1) '() (reverse coll)))
```

Is a better way to do this? I'm particularly frustrated by the fact that I have to reverse the input collection in order for this to work correctly. It seems somehow inelegant!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remember that you can efficiently insert at the end of a vector:

```
(defn map' [f coll]
  (reduce #(conj %1 (f %2)) [] coll))
```

Example:

```
(map' inc [1 2 3])
;=> [2 3 4]
```

One difference between this `map'` and the original `map` is that the original `map` returns an `ISeq` instead of just a `Seqable`:

```
(seq? (map inc [1 2 3]))
;=> true

(seq? (map' inc [1 2 3]))
;=> false
```

You could remedy this by composing the above implementation of `map'` with `seq`:

```
(defn map' [f coll]
  (seq (reduce #(conj %1 (f %2)) [] coll)))
```

The most important difference now is that, while the original `map` is lazy, this `map'` is eager, because `reduce` is eager.

Answer (score 13):

just for fun:
map really accepts more than one collection as an argument. Here is an extended implementation:

```
(defn map-with-reduce
  ([f coll] (seq (reduce #(conj %1 (f %2)) [] coll)))
  ([f coll & colls]
    (let [colls (cons coll colls)]
      (map-with-reduce (partial apply f)
                       (partition (count colls) 
                                  (apply interleave colls))))))
```

in repl:

```
user> (map-with-reduce inc [1 2 3])
(2 3 4)

user> (map-with-reduce + [1 2 3] [4 5] [6 7 8])
(11 14)
```

Answer (score 7):

The real map calls seq on its collection argument(s) and returns a lazy seq, so maybe this to get it a little closer to the real map?

```
(defn my-map
  [f coll]
  (lazy-seq (reduce #(conj %1 (f %2)) [] (seq coll))))
```

I would have added that as a comment, but I don't have the reputation. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `conj` to append to a vector instead of prepending to a list:

```
(defn my-map [f coll]
  (reduce (fn [result item]
              (conj result (f item)))
          [] coll))

(my-map inc [1 2 3]) => [2 3 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

It is more common to reverse the result, not the input.  This is a common idiom when handling singly-linked lists in a recursive fashion.  It preserves linear complexity with this data structure.

You might want to offer different implementations for other `seq`s, e. g., vectors, maybe based on `conj` instead of `cons`.

I would not worry too much about *elegance* with this kind of exercise.

Comment: I don't see why it makes a difference to reverse the result instead of the input; the complexity is linear either way.

Comment: @SamEstep: Yeah, OK.  It is just much more usual to reverse the result.

Comment: I don't really understand your comment about "offering other implementations for other `seq`s"; all the implementations of `map` on this page work for all `Seqable` inputs. If you mean to *produce* different types of sequences as a result, I don't see much of a point to doing that (except perhaps for performance) when one could easily just compose `map` with [`vec`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/vec) or something.

Comment: @SamEstep:  performance was exactly my point.  You do not need to reverse vectors.

Answer (score 1):

As it was already pointed out. You do not have to reverse the input. 
cons add an item to the beginning of a sequence (even on vectors) whereas conj will always add in the most natural way, it always add an item in the fastest way possible for the collection. it will add from left to right for list, and from left to right for vectors.

I noticed that most suggested answers use 'reduce' so allow me to suggest this one using mainly recursion:

```
(defn my-map [f coll]
 (loop [f f coll coll acc []]
   (if (empty? coll)
     acc
     (recur f (rest coll) (conj acc (f (first coll)))))))
```

Comment: The question specifically mentions using `reduce` so, whilst interesting, this answer in no way answers the question.

Comment: @mluisbrown that is true. I must have missed that it specifically stated to use 'reduce'